# Laravel Model Error Handling when Creating

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use Eloquent to create a DB entry like this:

```
   MFUser::create(array(
        'user_reference' => $this->userReference,
        'first_name' => $this->firstName,
        'last_name' => $this->lastName,
        'user_type_id' => $this->userTypeId,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password
    ));
```

It works well, except for the case, when exactly the same data is put into the fields, which is expected, as there should be no duplicate. I get the QueryExecption then.

But how do I properly perform error handling here to check if this query exception occurs so I can return a response from my server to the client via json then?

Comment: Why don't you use underscore instead of camelCase? This way you may pass info directly with the request, am I wrong?

Answer (score 19):

Just wrap that code in a `try`-`catch` block. Something like this:

```
try {
    MFUser::create(array(
        'user_reference' => $this->userReference,
        'first_name' => $this->firstName,
        'last_name' => $this->lastName,
        'user_type_id' => $this->userTypeId,
        'email' => $this->email,
        'password' => $this->password
    ));
} catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $exception) {
    // You can check get the details of the error using `errorInfo`:
    $errorInfo = $exception->errorInfo;

    // Return the response to the client..
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer to reserve `try/catch`'s for unexpected events that can't be handled elsewhere. In this case, you can utilise validation as a first measure, and the exception handler as a backup measure.

If the form request fails, the error messages are flashed and the user is returned to the previous page (where the form was submitted) and you can handle the messages gracefully. [Validation requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#other-validation-approaches)

```
// First line of defence - gracefully handle
// Controller 
public function store(MFUserRequest $request)
{
    // The incoming request is valid...
    MFUser::create(array(...));
}

// Form Request
class MFUserRequest extends Request 
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
        ];
    }    
}
```

Elsewhere, in your App\Exceptions directory you have the exception handler class that can be a catch all for various errors. Use this, when you haven't been able to gracefully handle it further down.

```
// Second line of defence - something was missed, and a model was  
// created without going via the above form request
namespace App\Exceptions;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {        
        if($e instanceof QueryException) {
            // log it or similar. then dump them back on the dashboard or general something bad
            // has happened screen
            return redirect()->route('/dashboard');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use validation you could still end up with race conditions.

Comment: How so? I don't think a race condition would occur?

Comment: If two people register with the same email simultaneously, they would both be validated because the email is not yet in the DB, but when the `create` method is called, it would fail for one of them, right?

Comment: That is a huuuuuuge edge case... I'm looking for the day my application is that popular that multiple users are registering with the same email address :) Regardless, assuming you have constraints on the db, the later one will fail, triggering the exception in the second snippet above

Comment: Yes for user registration with the same email its probably a huge edge case. But  there are scenarios where it may matter.

Comment: True, but for any case where it does truely matter, wouldn't you have db contraints on those fields so it would throw an error at the db level rather than allowing duplicate data coming in? I might be missing what you are saying, if you could provide an example?

Comment: I have an app where people regularly of the end of a seminar can register on the website. The course has up to 200 participants and each of them has a unique 8 digit license number. I want to avoid that multiple people can register with the same license number (they all register at the same time). So if a user registers, I try to insert his row with the license number, if it works, all good, if it does not work because of unique restraint, I catch the error, and tell the user that his license number has become invalid during his submission.

Comment: I obviously don't know your app as well as you do, but if the likelihood of a collision is high a different approach should be taken. In the case of a user with the (unlikely) case of using the same email at the same time, that is an exception by its very definition. In your case, it sounds far more typical - and shouldn't be treated as an exception but rather something that could occur frequently. However, with your app - I'm still a little confused, if they are issued unique codes, how are their clashes? Input errors by the user?

Comment: Yeah for sure. Hmm interesting one for sure.Is the project open source?

Answer (score 2):

Simply make use of `try / catch` block.

```
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;

// ...

try {
    // DB query goes here.
} catch (QueryException $e) {
    // Logics in case there are QueryException goes here
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`Try and Catch` something might help u and imagine for create try catch for all of them, but have best practice to handle all of QueryException, my recommend is use Laravel Exceptions Handler because it's make u easy for make execption global!

let's try it!, open `App\Exception\Handler.php` and at render method u can write like this one

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
   if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
      if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
          // example algo for make response
          return response()->json(['message' => 'xxx'], 403);
      }
   }

   return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

after that, u can get xxx json for every error request triggered by Query